# how to make Range filters on multiple field in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know that basically performing range filters on multiple fields like the code below is not allowed:

```
eventRef
    .whereField("dateTimeStart", isGreaterThan: startTime)
    .whereField("dateTimeStart", isLessThan: finishTime)
    .whereField("price", isGreaterThan: 10)
    .whereField("price", isLessThan: 1000)
```

I have to choose between performing filter based on "dateTimeStart" or just "price" in one query, but I need to filter based on those two criteria, is there any trick to do this? I just can think that I have to do query based on price only and then the result of the query need to be sorted manually

Is there any better option than this approach?

Comment: better if you fetch all records and save in list and then you can do anything with records

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the query in your code, you'll get for sure an error that sounds like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'dateTimeStart' and 'price'
```

So there is no way in Firestore to use `whereEqualTo()` function on more than one property. In this case, you should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup. So you should duplicate data by creating a new collection named `priceAndPeriod` in which you should add all your products that have the `price` between `10` and `1000` and also have the `dateTimeStart` between `startTime` and `finishTime`.

Note, there is no problem with duplicating data, when it comes to Firebase. This is a quite common practice, which is named `denormalization` and for that, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). It is for Firebase Real-time database but same principle applies to Cloud Firestore.

When you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: Hi, have you tried my solution above?